# Routing input to Bluetooth headset in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to record an audio (not a phone call) using the bluetooth input and not the device microphone?
I am able to playback whatever am saying through device's mic but not able to figure out how to use the bluetooth mic instead.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

(Edited)
I got it working by using following two lines of code
startBluetoothSco();
setBluetoothScoOn(true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the bluetooth headset play back whatever am saying by using 
STREAM_VOICE_CALL in audioTrack initialization.